# How to repeat a list of items from a vector in hiccup?

Tags: clojure, hiccup

If I have a vector name-lst as ["John" "Mary" "Watson" "James"],

and I want to diplay them as list items, how do I do that using hiccup ?

something like

```
[:ul 
  (for [name name-list]
    [:li name])]
```

will return a list of [:li ] in between [:ul ] instead of just repeating.
There must be something better. I am relatively new to hiccup, I searched but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you feed the data structure to Hiccup you should get the expected result:

```
(require '[hiccup.core :refer [html]])

(def names
  ["John" "Mary" "Watson" "James"])

(html [:ul 
       (for [name names]
         [:li name])])
;=> "<ul><li>John</li><li>Mary</li><li>Watson</li><li>James</li></ul>"
```

Comment: but for will return a list: ([:li "John"] [:li "Mary"] [:li "Watson"] [:li "James"]) 

will html conversion still work?

Comment: `(html (for [name names] [:li name]))` => `"<li>John</li><li>Mary</li><li>Watson</li><li>James</li>"`

Comment: I tried. it works. hiccup is the most compact DSL for clojure I have seen :)